# Cannot change the visiblity of an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a ListView using a custom cursoradapter to fill the ListView.

The `row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="0dip"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/title"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:ellipsize="marquee"
           android:textSize="24dp" />
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/artist"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:ellipsize="marquee"
           android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/currentplaying"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
       android:contentDescription="@string/now_playing"
       android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the ImageView's visibility is gone. I want to make it
visible for one particular row. Here is the code I tried but it is not
working...

```
View view = getListView().getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.currentplaying);
iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
        holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    if(position==0) {     
        holder.imgViewLogo.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT:

I got it working. I used this to start the ListView activity.

```
intent.putExtra("id", c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID)));
startActivity(intent);
```

In the ListView activity,

```
currentplayingid = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
```

Then I added this in `bindview()`

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.currentplaying);
int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID));
if (id == SongsListActivity.this.currentplayingid)
    imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    imgview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); or iv.setVisibility(1); not working?

Comment: Try using View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE if it suits your needs. And try doing this in the code rather than xml file.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. I used this to start the list view activity.

```
intent.putExtra("id", c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID)));
startActivity(intent);
```

In the listview activity,

```
currentplayingid = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
```

Then i added this in bindview()

```
ImageView imgview = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.currentplaying);
int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper._ID));
if ( id == SongsListActivity.this.currentplayingid )
imgview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
imgview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you should do it in `getView()` of your adapter

EDIT:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // codes...

    if (position == 0)
    {
        holder.imgViewLogo.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.imgViewLogo.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
    }

    // codes...
}
```

Comment: The problem i get while using it in getView() is everytime i scroll, every 0th row's imageview becomes visible on the screen.

Comment: what do you mean by "every 0th row"?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't try it in getView(). I actually tried it in bindView(). Can you give me an example to work on in getView()?

Comment: How do i get the imageview's object in getview()?

Comment: like what have been done in the code you provided; first you inflate the row layout, then you can get the `ImageView` by `findViewById()`, after that, check if position == 0, if yes, set `ImageView` visible, if no, set it gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this

```
iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Using View.VISIBLE instead of ImageView.VISIBLE is not working.

Comment: What for image button ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code as follows,

```
     private class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView imgViewLogo;

}

  @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

        holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

       if(position==0)
     {     
    holder.imgViewLogo.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    return convertView;
}
```

It Works for me...It may help you.

Comment: I don't want it to happen when an listitem is clicked. I want to make the imageview visible for one row when the listview is displayed.

Comment: sorry i have understood your requirement wrongly. check the updated answer.

Comment: I have two textviews in my row. Check my row.xml above. They do not display any text anymore. And when i scroll down the list, the imageview is visible  for some other rows which i'm guessing is because of view recycling mentioned by Joel Skrepnek in a previous reply.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems where several widgets would appear for some rows but not for others.  The problems were due to view recycling.  I'm not exactly sure if that's your issue here, but you should handle it anyway.  The trick is to set visibility for every row; instead of just for the row that you want to appear/disappear.

So:

```
if (position == 0)
{
    iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    iv.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
}
```

Otherwise, you're assuming that for positions other than 0 the visibility is GONE but that might not be the case with view recycling.  I do this work in bindView, by the way.  Not sure if that's technically correct.

Comment: How do i find out the position in bindView()?

Answer (score 0):

If it is working some time then may be i can help you. What happen that whenever you move you listview it recreates all views again in this case it never save the last state of view. So what you need to do is to save state of your each imageview and in getView() you have to set accordingly.I am posting one of my answer it may help you.
Here is a little code for your help: I will create a boolean arraylist.

private ArrayList imageview_visible      = null;

Then I will set states of all imageview as false in my constructor:

```
for (int i=0; i < no_of_elements.size(); i++) {
    imageview_visible.add(i, false);
}
```

In your getView write this code:

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
     //WRITE YOUR CODE

```
 if (imageview_visible.get(position) == true)
 {
     //SET YOUR IMAGE VIEW AS VISIBLE
 } else {
    // SET IMAGEVIEW AS GONE
 }
```

}

Whenever you unhide or hide your view just save it into imageview_visible.set(true or false) this will save state of you all imageview and set every image view accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutInflater to get view object

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.currentplaying);
iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: view object is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue... i solved with a non standar solution, but worked for me...

```
v.setImageResource(R.color.transparent);
```

importing R from android

```
import android.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);` are correcte but It's better to use `View` instead of `ImageView` because `VISIBLE` & `GONE` are defined in `View` class.

You most change Both Visibility (`VISIBLE` or `GONE`) in that `if`. like:

```
if(?)
    iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide or show views using setVisibility(int) . 
use `iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`